# How to search a word from an array of model which is inside a model array in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsarray, nspredicate

What is the best and easiest way to search a word from an array of model which is inside another model array. For example, I have an array which contains model class for students. So students has more than one teacher which is in array of teachers model class. And when i search teacher name , i need to get list of students who has that teacher. I know how to search using `predicate` from a array of model class.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",@"sarah"];
searchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[studentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

I tried this but its not working.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.teachers.teacherName contains[c] %@",@"sarah"];
```

**Student Model class will looks like this.**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *teachers;
```

I know how to do this with splitting array and get it using for loops. Can any one help me to find me an easiest way. Thank you.

Comment: Show me Students Modal Class.

Comment: Consider having also the inverse relationship. Every time you add a teacher to a student, add the student to an array of students in the teacher model.

Comment: No there is no inverse relation, the values are coming from backend.

Answer (score 1):

okay lets say, your model class has below properties as you mentioned,
for example in `Student.h` file

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface Student : NSObject
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; //i am changing it to strong 
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *teachers;
 - (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name trachers:(NSArray *)teachers address:(NSString *)address;
 @end
```

and in `Student.m` file

```
#import "Student.h"
@implementation Student

//custom initialiser 
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name trachers:(NSArray *)teachers address:(NSString *)address
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
       self.name = name;
       self.teachers = teachers;
       self.address = address;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

and in `ViewController.m` file i am creating the instance of the Student and adding it to array for example,

in `ViewController.h` file,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Student.h"
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *students; //to hold student instances
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;//to search the teachers 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;//to display the output
@end
```

and in `ViewController.m` file,

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   _students = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for(int k = 0 ; k < 5 ; k++)
   {
       NSMutableArray *teachers = [self getTeachersForStudent:k];//a helper method to fill teacher's name
       Student *stud = [[Student alloc] initWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"student_%d",k] trachers:teachers address:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"address_%d",k]]; //hear student name will be like "student_0"
       [_students addObject:stud]; //finally add it to students array
   }
}

//this is the helper method, for testing u can add different same name if you want 
- (NSMutableArray *)getTeachersForStudent:(int)k
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    switch (k)
    {
       case 0:
           [array addObjectsFromArray:@[@"anoop",@"shan",@"sara",@"peter",@"david",@"gopi"]];
       break;
       case 1:
           [array addObjectsFromArray:@[@"hema",@"isah",@"sara",@"john"]];
       break;
       case 2:
           [array addObjectsFromArray:@[@"venu",@"giri",@"kim",@"madu",@"shan"]];
       break;
       case 3:
           [array addObjectsFromArray:@[@"venu",@"tom",@"yesh",@"vijay",@"shan"]];
       break;
       case 4:
           [array addObjectsFromArray:@[@"vim",@"janu",@"jai",@"kiran",@"shan"]];
       break;
       default:
          break;
   }
   return array;
 }
```

finally the sorting function in the `ViewController.m` file add below method, it will take the initial string from search bar and searches the all teachers name and finally gives the student name that will be displayed in the textview

```
 - (void)refreshStudentList
  {
     __block NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [_students enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Student*  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
      __block Student *presentStudent = obj;
      __block NSArray *array = [presentStudent valueForKey:@"teachers"];
      [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
           if([obj rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [result addObject:presentStudent];
            }
      }];
   }];
  //at this point result array contains all the student student name of the teacher that u are searched 
   NSString *resultString = @"";
   for(Student *s in result)
   {
      resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", resultString, s.name];
   }
   _textView.text = resultString;
 }
```

add the searhbar delegate method in same `ViewController.m` and call `refreshStudentList` method

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
 {
    [self refreshStudentList];
    if (searchText.length == 0)
       _textView.text = @"";  //simply resetting the text view 
}
```

finally the output will be like below

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was looking some thing using predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet. It will work

```
NSArray *allIds = YOURARRAY
__block NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[allIds enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",@"sarah"];
        searchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[studentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
       [newArray addObject:searchArray];
}];
NSLog(@"%d", [newArray count]);
```

Comment: what should be in 'allIds'  should contain?

Comment: allIds is your array object "studentArray"

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVC operators in your NSPredicate, doing something like:

```
predicate =
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"teachers.lastName CONTAINS %@", @"Petter" ];
filtered  = [studentsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

@mattt wrote a good example in their NSHipster article (http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) about KVC operators in collections, which maybe will be useful to you.

Comment: no i tried this, its not working , actually i updated it in my question was a mistake accidentally i put 'name' instead of  'teachers'.